# How to insert current Date and Time using PostgreSQL DB and retrieve it back in a particular format?

Tags: java, postgresql, date, time

For example, I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE MESSAGES(
MESSAGE_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
SENT TIMESTAMP  NOT NULL
);
```

While in my java class I have taken message_id as integer and sent as calendar.

My query goes something like this:

While Inserting (just showing for the date part):

```
    String sql1="insert into messages (message_id,sent)  values (?,?)";
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    ps1.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
```

After inserting the Table view is:

message_id       sent

---

```
 1       | 2016-12-22 00:00:00
 2       | 2016-6-22 00:00:00
```

While retrieving (just showing for the date part):

```
    String sql="select message_id, sent from messages";
    Messages msg=new Messages();
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();   
    Date d=rs.getDate("sent");  
    String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a";
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    String conDate=simpleDateFormat.format(d);
```

I get the dates but time is always 12:00:00 AM.
I want to show get it in a format like this :

"The message was sent on 2016-12-3 19:30:00 PM"

Am I doing anything wrong? Any kind Help is appreciated... :)

Comment: `hh` is the hour in AM/PM you want `HH`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: The way I read [Using Java 8 Date and Time classes](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/8-date-time.html), if you can use the `java.time` classes and the newest PostgrSQL JDBC driver, you should pass a `LocalDateTime` to your prepared statement and ask to have a `LocalDateTime` back from the result set. This is good news since these classes are much nicer to work with than `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date only means 'day' in JDBC. Use timestamp if you want to have the time, too.

Edit:
What I was talking about is:

```
String sql1="insert into messages (message_id,sent)  values (?,?)";
ps1.setTimestamp(2, java.sql.TimeStamp.from(Instant.now()));
```

and

```
String sql="select message_id, sent from messages";
Messages msg=new Messages();
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();   
java.util.Date d=rs.getTimestamp("sent");  
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
String conDate=simpleDateFormat.format(d);
```

None of this is deprecated as far as I know, and if so I don't have a more modern solution. Still waiting for JDBC to support new time API...
And getDate / new java.sql.Date will cut of the time, and that's not what you want.

Comment: Timestamp is depricated. Do you have any other way to do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: try with "timestamp without time zone" .Thats what i use in postgres.

Comment: @SumeetBarua, “Timestamp is deprecated”? In Java or in PostgreSQL? That’s new to me.

Comment: @OleV.V. Use of timestamp is depricated in Java. In postgreSQL it just the data type.

Comment: @Ankur Can you please help me with the syntax while inserting the date value?

Comment: Only one of the ctor of `Timestamp` is deprecated.  Usage of `Timestamp` is still fine. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html

Comment: Yes and no, @AdrianShum. You are completely correct that the `java.sql.Timestamp` class is not marked as deprecated. At the same time there is a newer and better substitute in `java.time.LocalDateTime` (in this case; in other cases `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime `is better). As I said in a comment to the question, the PostgreSQL JDBC docs say that the JDBC driver can work with these.

Comment: @OleV.V. I am aware of the JSR310 being better choice in date-time.  However it is actually out of my interest here as I am just responding OP's comment on "Timestamp is depricated", while on the same time in his question he is still using `java.sql.Date`

Comment: @Sir RotN ...The solution just works fine. A "BIG THANKS" to all of you. Each and every comment was truly accountable.